# Send only one property of object in response node.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Want to send on Title of my subcategory in response. Tried like this but not getting anything can anyone tell me how to do that.

```
exports.Subcategory= (req, res) => {
    var sub = {}
    Subcategory.findById(req.params.id, function (err, subcategory)     {
        console.log(typeof(subcategory))
        res.send({ sub: subcategory.Tittle})
    });
};
```

Here is my collection

```
"_id": "5c398e8fd301362158004fd1",
"Description": "value",
"Slug": "value",
"category_id": "5c398ac7d301362158004fcd",
"UserId": "5c3796cad3013606e8001f9c",
"updated_at": "2019-01-12T06:51:59.000Z",
"created_at": "2019-01-12T06:51:59.000Z"
```

And from this 'category_id' want to find the category information from 'category' collection and send through response

Comment: There is no `Title` field on the Subcategory document, perhaps you meant the `Slug` field?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use populate in mongoose try like this 
In your SubCategory schema

```
const SubCategory = new Schema({category_id:{type:String, ref:'Category'}); // to make the relation with Category model


exports.Subcategory= (req, res) => {
    var sub = {}
    Subcategory.find({_id:req.params.id}).populate('category_id').exec((err,data)=>{
       res.send({ data:data});
    });
```